# Why am I getting a 404 error when I submit my Blazor Server form?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-5.0

I created a new Blazor Server project in Visual Studio 2019 using .NET Core 5.x.

I created a new page `Search.razor` and put it in the `/Pages` directory.

I created a new page `SearchResults.razor` and put it in the `/Pages` directory.

My **Search.razor** looks like this:

```
@page "/search"

<h3>Search</h3>

<form method="GET" action="SearchResults.razor">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    ... future form elements here
    <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>

@code {

}
```

My **SearchResults.razor** looks like this:

```
@page "/searchresults"

<h3>SearchResults</h3>

@code {

}
```

I modified the **/Shared/NavMenu.razor** page to look like this:

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        ...
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="search">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Search
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I start the app, click the "Search" link in the right menu, enter the name "joe smith" into the search field, click the Submit button, and receive this from Chrome:

```
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address:
https://localhost:44314/SearchResults.razor?name=joe+smith
HTTP ERROR 404
```

The address bar contains this:

```
https://localhost:44314/SearchResults.razor?name=joe+smith
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"SearchResults.razor"` is not a valid address.

A quick sketch of how it could work:

```
@page "/search"
<EditForm Model="this" OnValidSubmit="DoSearch">
    <InputText @bind-Value="search" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private string search;
    void DoSearch()
    {
        var arg = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(search);
        Navigator.NavigateTo($"searchresults/{arg}");
    }
}
```

and the receiving end, UrlDecode comes for free:

```
@page "/searchresults/{text?}"
<h3>SearchResults</h3>
<p>Looking for @Text</p>    

@code {

  [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; }


}
```